# Prevent image from changing color when written to a new TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, colors, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I've been working on optimizing color PNG images for storage size by using the TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED BufferedImage to limit the number of unique colors each image can contain. I noticed that when I save an existing image to this format, the white (255,255,255) background color becomes an off-white color (252,252,252).

Is there any way to prevent this color shift from happening? I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566590/disable-dithering-on-a-type-byte-indexed-bufferedimage) which has a solution but it feels very hacky and is much slower than the Graphics2D implementation of drawImage.

Here's my code currently that's producing this issue. The original image is being loaded as a TYPE_3BYTE_BGR BufferedImage.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageOutputPath.toFile());
BufferedImage indexedImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED);
Graphics2D g = indexedImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
g.dispose();
```

I know that this type of BufferedImage supports white as I've tried adding white margins around the image and it displays correctly but with the off-white image centered on the page. It just seems like the white in my image isn't converting correctly.

Any ideas and help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Beware that when you use a `BufferedImage` of type `TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED` like this, you will get a fixed hard coded palette of colors, that may not be well suited for your image. There is a separate constructor that takes an `IndexColorModel` as a param that you can use instead (after selecting the best colors, which is a topic in itself). Still, this does not explain what you see, perhaps the "white" in your input isn't exactly (255,255,255)?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847092/given-an-rgb-value-what-would-be-the-best-way-to-find-the-closest-match-in-the-d

Comment: For some reason, the question to which you’ve linked tried setting some rendering hints in the Graphics object, but never bothered to try [KEY_COLOR_RENDERING](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/RenderingHints.html#KEY_COLOR_RENDERING), which appears to be designed to address this very issue.  I would try setting it to VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY before calling drawImage.

Comment: @HaraldK I just verified by using the bit shifting method described in the top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761438/understanding-bufferedimage-getrgb-output-values) and confirmed that it is exactly (255,255,255).

Comment: @VGR I've tried all three different value settings for the KEY_COLOR_RENDERING hint and none of them made any difference in the resulting image that I could see. When centered on a centered on a white fillRect drawing, the color of the original image is noticeably darker gray. I've also tried different values for KEY_DITHERING, KEY_RENDERING, and KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION with no luck.

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me. You can report it at https://bugs.java.com/. 

Comment: Looks like this was already reported a long time ago and Oracle chose to not fix it. [link](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6503035)